# Rails 4 rspec UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, routes

I am testing a Rails app that has been upgraded to Rails 4.2 using rspec 3.4.1. In this app I have the following route (as printed by `rake routes`):

```
contact_g  GET /foo/contact/:legs_trip_id/:user_id(.:format)
           foo#find_edit { :trip_type_id=>"123", :user_id=>"0", :locale=>"en", :format=>/html|js|json/, :legs_trip_id=>/\d+/}
```

In my app, in development and production modes, this route works fine. But in tests I get the following error when trying to use the route. Example spec:

```
describe "#find_edit, logged in:" do
before do
  @c1 = mock_model(Foo, :id => 1059)
  # mock a User, set up session and expectations to mimick a logged in user
  @u = pseudo_login
end
it "..." do
  expect(@u).to receive # ...
  get :find_edit, :legs_trip_id => "123", :pn_id => 252, :sa_id => 1923, :email => 1, :ee_id => "bla", :trip_type_id => "123", user_id: @u.id
  expect(response).to redirect_to(...)
end
```

As a controller test, at the "get" line rspec throws this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches { :action=>"find_edit", :controller=>"foo", :ee_id=>"bla", :email=>"1", :legs_trip_id=>"123", :pn_id=>"252", :sa_id=>"1923", :trip_type_id=>"123", :user_id=>"19" }
```

As a feature or integration specI  can't access `request.session` to login my mocked user and thus can't get the tests to start at all:

```
   undefined local variable or method `request' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::FindingByLTAndUserIDFindEditLoggedIn:...>
```

in this helper code that is called during spec setup:

```
request.session[:user_id] = mocked_user.id
```

How can I run these specs? It used to work in Rails 3.x.

Comment: notice that `rake routes` tells you that :user_id is always zero while :legs_trip_id is a number(`:user_id => "0",:legs_trip_id => \/d+\}`)

Comment: try to replace `@u.id` with 0 to see if your test succeeds

Comment: Same error with 0 instead of @u.id. This would have been strange since the "0" is just a default value if I understand correctly. Also, in the console, `app.url_for(...)` with the same parameters fails, but `app.contact_g_url(legs_trip_id: '123')` succeeds.

Comment: try the test without passing :user_id altogether

Comment: still same UrlGenerationError